expo-background-fetch - task is never executed
Using example and following tutorial for expo-background-fetch I didn't see the function triggered. (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/)
Same with the following code:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';

const BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK = 'background-fetch';

function myTask() {
  try {
    // Fetch data here...
    const backendData = "Simulated fetch " + new Date().toLocaleString();
  
    console.log("myTask() ", backendData);
    return backendData; // Return the fetched data directly
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', err);
    return null;
  }
}

export async function initBackgroundFetch() {
  console.log("Init Background Fetch");
  try {
    if (!TaskManager.isTaskDefined(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK)) {
      TaskManager.defineTask(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, myTask);
    }
    const options = {
      minimumInterval: 1 * 60
    };
    await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, options);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("registerTaskAsync() failed:", err);
  }
}



async function unregisterBackgroundFetchAsync() {
  return BackgroundFetch.unregisterTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK);
}

export default function BackgroundFetchScreen() {
  const [isRegistered, setIsRegistered] = useState(false);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
  const [backendData, setBackendData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    initBackgroundFetch();
    checkStatusAsync();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await myTask();
      setBackendData(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(); // Fetch data when component mounts
  }, []);

  const checkStatusAsync = async () => {
    const status = await BackgroundFetch.getStatusAsync();
    const isRegistered = await TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK);
    setStatus(status);
    setIsRegistered(isRegistered);
  };

  return (
    <Text>
      Background:{' '}
      <Text style={styles.boldText}>
        {status && BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchStatus[status]}
      </Text>
      Status:{' '}
      <Text style={styles.boldText}>
        {isRegistered ? "Registered" : 'Not registered yet!'}
      </Text>
      Last update:{' '}
      <Text style={styles.boldText}>
        {backendData ? backendData : 'No data fetched yet!'}
      </Text>
    </Text>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  textContainer: {
    margin: 10,
  },
  boldText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

From the previous snippet i get only the following output, also waiting a long time:
 LOG  Init Background Fetch
 LOG  myTask()  Simulated fetch 10/04/2024, 14:48:27

I'm running expo with npx expo start on a windows machine targeting an ipad (ios) that runs expo go.
There are known bugs o specific example for that use?
Thanks

So you mean the BackgroundTask should be executed periodictly ?
Did you try to trigger the BackgroundFetch with Xcode Instruments, in case you have access to a Mac ?

Yes, it must run every X minutes. No access to mac or xcode. Now tried to make a build but the result is the same ('logging' by saving the data to a local db)

iOS is awful and as a result background tasks are insanely unreliable. You cannot trust them to fire when you request them, or frankly, at all. If you look around, you'll see even Apple's own apps like the clock fail to fire alarms when intended. It's a disaster. I'd recommend you test on Android to know your code is correct - then try to find a way to work around Apple's ineptitude (I have never found one.)
